# First fictional film to show Aikido

Tags: aikido, history, entertainment

I was wondering what was the first fictional film to show more than one Aikido technique<sup>1</sup>. I am assuming that the 1988 [Above The Law](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094602/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_55) might be it but it there might be something else.

---

<sup><sub>**1** Let's assume more than one technique done differently. So, a dozen kotegaeshi would not really fit but add an ikkajo and all is good.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen references to the 1982 film, *[The Challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Challenge_(1982_film))*, prominently showing Aikido (Seagal was a fight coordinator).

> The Challenge is a 1982 American action film directed by John Frankenheimer and co-written by John Sayles. The film stars Scott Glenn and Toshirō Mifune. It is noted that this film features several aikido-based action scenes choreographed by Steven Seagal, prior to the start of his own film career.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEL08kvdNEY

Comment: I feel like there is likely a case somewhere of an earlier usage, albeit possibly not featured, since the martial art has been around since the advent of film, but I have not figured out a good way to search for it.

Answer (score 2):

By searching for "Aikido film" on Google I found this one from 1975: [*The Defensive Power of Aikido*](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0165296/) not sure if this meets your requirements though, since it's about the actual founder, Morihei Ueshiba.

Comment: It is not a documentary, though - IMDB says it is an Action Movie.

Comment: It's probably some sort of biopic like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ip_Man_(film) ...